# jQuery search bar only working one time per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, multiple-instances

I am working on a page for pre-registration to events on my website. On this page, people need the ability to add names into as many slots as the event creator would like (so it needs to handle 3 person basketball teams and 50 person banquets). I have had a high quality facebook-like search bar made so that I can neatly search through the database and select the desired people. Sadly I have this search bar being created by a for loop that creates many different ID filled search bars but every one of them is left empty and the first search bar is the only one that is filled.

I found that it deals with the jQuery code at the top of my page. My question/issue is that I need this jQuery to work on multiple search bars on a single page. If anyone can help me accomplish this I'd be greatly appreciative.

The "top code" or JQuery code that pulls from the db successfully is:

```
$(function(){
    $(".search").keyup(function() 
    { 
    var inputSearch = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'searchword='+ inputSearch;
    if(inputSearch!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../searchMyChap.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#divResult").html(html).show();
        }
        });
    }return false;    
    });

    jQuery("#divResult").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#inputSearch').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
        jQuery("#divResult").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    $('#inputSearch').click(function(){
        jQuery("#divResult").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ 
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.contentArea{
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/*
#inputSearch
{
    width:350px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    padding:3px;
}
*/
#divResult
{
    position:absolute;
    width:545px;
    display:none;
    margin-top:-1px;
    border:solid 1px #dedede;
    border-top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border-width: 3px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #333 #DEDEDE #DEDEDE;
    background-color: white;
}
.display_box
{
    padding:4px; border-top:solid 1px #dedede; 
    font-size:12px; height:50px;
}
.display_box:hover
{
    background:#0088cc;
    //background:#3bb998;

    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The for-loop code that prints the search bars is as follows:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $looper; $i++)
                                        {
                                            echo'
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                                        <label>Member Name:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control search" name="member'.$i.'" autocomplete="off" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Search...">
                                                    <div id="divResult" style="z-index:999; margin-top: 35px;" ></div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>';
                                        }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$looper`? What is its value?

Comment: JQuery's `live` has been deprecated and removed for a long time. You should be using `on()`

Comment: @sdgluck $looper is pulling from a count. It works fine. That's not the issue.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you! I had a freelancer make this bit for me so I will look into updating it. Would switching it to on() fix my issue or was that just a general suggestion.?

Comment: Problem is you can only have one element with one id. There are mutliple elements with the same id

Comment: @epascarello is there any way to have the id increment like it does in the for loop? like "#divResult'.$i.'" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/4c5bddn8/)

---

The first issue is that with each iteration of the `for` loop an element is created with `id="divResult"`. An ID should be used once in the whole document. I have changed the `for` loop to produce an element with `class="divResult"` instead. If you use this change, remember that your CSS will need to be changed accordingly.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $looper; $i++) {
  echo '
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Member Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control search" name="member'.$i.'" autocomplete="off" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Search...">
          <div class="divResult" style="z-index:999; margin-top: 35px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Next we iterate over each `.search` element. Within each iteration we can find the corresponding 'result' element by using jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function, which retrieves the immediately following sibling of an element. If the code is ever changed such that the 'results' element does *not* appear straight after the `.search' element, this will need changing.

```
$(function () {
    $('.search').each(function(index) {
        var $searchElement = $(this);
        var $resultElement = $searchElement.next();

        console.log(index, $searchElement, $resultElement);

        $searchElement.on('keyup', function() {
            var inputSearch = $searchElement.val();
            var dataString = 'searchword=' + inputSearch;

            if (inputSearch != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../searchMyChap.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $resultElement.html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });

        $resultElement.on("click", function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(this);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
            $searchElement.val(decoded);
        });

        $(document).on("click", function (e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
                $resultElement.fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $searchElement.on('click', function () {
            console.log(index + ' clicked');
            $resultElement.fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That is exactly the direction I was going with it but as soon as I change the id to class the entire search bar stops working and equal spaces appear on my page. I tried implementing your code and it didn't seem to fix the problem with the code appearing. Thank you so much for that though!

Comment: Did you change the selector `#divResult` to `.divResult` in your CSS?

Comment: Yes I just did and while that gets rid of the spacing on the page it doesn't get the box to appear when typing into the search bar. I feel like much closer to the solution though!

Comment: As I hadn't tested my answer, there were of course some bugs! So... here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/4c5bddn8/).
Note: do not copy the `for` loop from here, take it from my original answer as it has been changed from PHP to JavaScript in the JSFiddle.